# Kubernetes kube-apiserver to kubelet permissions

Tags: kubernetes

What controls the permissions when you call

`kubectl logs pod-name` ?

I've played around and tried calling the kubelet api from on of the controller nodes.

`sudo curl -k --key /var/lib/kubernetes/cert-k8s-apiserver-key.pem --cert /var/lib/kubernetes/cert-k8s-apiserver.pem https://worker01:10250/pods`

This fails with `Forbidden (user=apiserver, verb=get, resource=nodes, subresource=proxy)`.

I've tried the same call using the admin key and cert and it succeeds and return a healthy blob of JOSN.

I'm guessing this is why `kubectl logs pod-name` doesn't work.

A little more reading suggests that the CN of the certificate determines the user that is authenticated and authorized.

What controls whether a user is authorized to access the kubelet API?

*Background*

I'm setting up a K8s cluster using the following instructions [Kubernetes the not so hard way with Ansible](https://www.tauceti.blog/posts/kubernetes-the-not-so-hard-way-with-ansible-the-basics/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer

The short answer is that you need to grant the user `apiserver` access to the resource `node` by creating a ClusterRole and ClusterRoleBinding.

### Longer Explanation

Kubernetes has a bunch of resources. The relevant ones here are:

- Role
- Node
- [ClusterRole](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole)
- [ClusterRoleBinding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding)

Roles and ClusterRoles are similar, except ClusterRoles are not namespaced.

A ClsuterRole can be associated (bound) to a user with a ClusterRoleBinding object.

Kubelet provides some resources (maybe more)

- `nodes/proxy`
- `nodes/stats`
- `nodes/log`
- `nodes/spec`
- `nodes/metrics`

To make this work, you need to create a ClusterRole that allow access to the resource and sub-resource on the Node.

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  annotations:
    rbac.authorization.kubernetes.io/autoupdate: "true"
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/bootstrapping: rbac-defaults
  name: system:kube-apiserver-to-kubelet
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - nodes/proxy
      - nodes/stats
      - nodes/log
      - nodes/spec
      - nodes/metrics
    verbs:
      - "*"
EOF
```

Then you associate this ClusteRole with a user. In my case, the kube-apiserver is using a certificate with `CN=apiserver`.

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply --kubeconfig admin.kubeconfig -f -
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: system:kube-apiserver
  namespace: ""
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: system:kube-apiserver-to-kubelet
subjects:
  - apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
    kind: User
    name: apiserver
EOF
```